# Export multiple jar files - Scability problem

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I'm trying to export multiple java files into runnable jar files in eclipse.
I know how to do it. My problem is scability, because for now I'm only exporting 10 files each time I made changes. But later on the project I'll probably have more files. For example now I'm losing like 5 minutes for 10 files, later on I'll lose 50 minutes for 100 files..

Is there any way to export them all at once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably be using a build tool such as [tag:maven] or [tag:gradle] for that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a build system like [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and use a mechanism to build a jar. In Gradle, you can use custom jar tasks for that

build.gradle

```
fileTree(dir: "src").each { javaFile ->
    def jarTask = task(javaFile as String, type: Jar) {
        from(javaFile)
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': javaFile.toString().replace('/', '.')
        }
    }
    task.build dependsOn jarTask
}
```

Then all you need to do is to invoke from command line

```
gradle build
```

And everything is done for you automatically (most IDEs also support a visual trigger).

Comment: But that will convert all my project's files into one jar, right?
What I wanted is to create one jar for each java class that I have in my project.

Comment: Oh, that's a strange use case, but should be still easily doable with gradle, I'll update my answer.

Comment: What am I supposed to do with that code? Sould I put in my settings.gradle file? Or build.gradle file?

Comment: And how do I invoke gradle build?

Comment: I updated my answer, but please also read a bit about gradle.

Comment: What do you mean by command line? My IDE command line? Or my windows command line?